# What's the meaning of "subject to"?

Tags: meaning

> Earth is a target in a cosmic shooting gallery, **subject to** random violent events that were unsuspected a few decades ago.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning in this case is that earth is open to or vulnerable to collisions by objects in space. The image is that of the earth being the intended target in a shooting gallery. The random passage of objects passing earth is different than the intention of shooters.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Oxford English Dictionary, the word *subject* is here used in its adjectival form:

> *Adjective*: 1. Likely or pone to be affected by (a particular condition or occurrence, typically an unwelcome or unpleasant one).